# I want to save the Hangout session

Tags: google-plus

I need to save the hangout session(like text messages,voice and video) in my server. Is it possible to do that using Hangouts API.

Are the any other tools to do this ?.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Hangout API does not provide access to the video/audio stream, nor the in-hangout chat. In theory, you could implement your own chat app, but everyone in the hangout would need to use it.

The only way to get a recording of the audio/video at the moment is to either use a screen grabber, or to use a Hangout on Air (possibly by starting it through YouTube Live) to record it on YouTube.